# Is that possible to set a multi-line textbox a background image?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox control (multi-line enabled). Is that possible to assign it a background image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a WinForms application?

There is no 'built-in' way of doing this.  You can override the controls paint method (onPaintBackground - I believe) and draw the image yourself.

If it's Web based or WPF - you're in luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just add the image location to the text box styling:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" style="background-image: url( images/myTextboxImage.jpg ); border: none;" />
```

EDIT: As Rob pointed out in his answer: this is only if you're doing it on the web.